# matlab mex error no file name given

Tags: matlab, mex

When I type in mex -c mexNodeSurroundings.mexw64 into MATLAB, I get the error "no file name given". I'm wondering what the cause of this is, since the filename 'mexNodeSurroundings.mexw64' is in the current directory. Any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 0):

A `mex` file (`.mexw64`) isn't recognized as a source file for compilation.  Give it the name of the *input* file, the one you want to compile.

Here's the example given from [online documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/building-mex-files.html#brnq88l-1):

> Use the mex function to build the binary MEX-file. If you are using a
>   C/C++ compiler, type:
>   mex timestwo.c
>
> If you are using a Fortran compiler, type:
>   mex timestwo.F
>
> This command creates the file timestwo.ext, where ext
>   is the value returned by the mexext function. You call timestwo as if
>   it were a MATLAB function. For example, at the MATLAB command prompt,
>   type:
>
> timestwo(4) MATLAB displays:
>   ans =
>        8

Comment: I must be confused then? I thought I wanted to compile the .mexw64 file.

Comment: You compile a `.c/.cpp/.h/.F` file *into* a `.mexw64` file.  Once it has been `mex`ed, you can call it from matlab.  The file you mention has *already* been generated by `mex`